# SSRS report grouping (AX 2012)

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, ssrs-grouping

I'm modifying the sales invoice report.
What I want to do is to group lines by LineHeader. 
i.e. if invoice has 6 lines and 3 salesid, report should be like:

LineHeader {2 lines below}, LineHeader {2 lines below}, LineHeader {2 lines below}.

How to group to achieve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sales invoice report has two datasets, one for the overall invoice header, and one for the lines. The way I understand your question, you would like a sub header within the invoice details.

If you look in the report design in Visual Studio, you will find a tablix that is associated with the SalesInvoiceDS dataset, which comes from the SalesInvoiceTmp temp table. if you highlight the tablix, you can see the groups defined within its dataset:

[image: View Group on Tablix]

Right clicking on a group (table16_Details_group in the picture) and pressing "Group Properties..." brings up the Group Properties dialog box. from here you can add a group expression and set it to the whatever field you want to group by:

[image: Select Group By Field]

Note you will need to add the field to the salesInvoiceTmp table and modify the report data provider to populate it if it does not already exist. This is outside the scope of this answer, but there are numerous resources on the web and in books that show you how to do this (I recommend [this](https://www.packtpub.com/application-development/microsoft-dynamics-ax-2012-reporting-cookbook) book, I've found it very helpful with regard to the Report Data Provider framework.)

Now viewing the tablix with a field highlighted, you can see an orange bracket-like line to the left of each group. Everything within this bracket is repeated for every "Group" that the group by statement defines. You would then right click the Row group again, and press Add Group > Child Group, and set its group by statement to ItemId.

The bracket to the left will now have a smaller bracket within it. The outer bracket correlates to the salesId group, and the inner to the items within that group. The line header row would be inside the larger bracket but outside the smaller bracket, and will repeat for each SalesId, while the item details will be within the smaller, and repeat for each item. This is a bit difficult to describe in text, but you can always highlight a field, and the corresponding group will highlight as well.

Note that adding these groups to semi-complex tablices tends to mess them up, so it may be better to create one from scratch and define the groups before putting your data into it.

Comment: Hello,
thanks for your great answer, it helped me a lot.
I have additional thing to do that I'm not very sure how.
I want to have two sub total fields. in cases when we have several pages on report, the first sub-total1 field should be zero at the begining (on page 1) and sub-total2 should be total amount of lines (sum). If there are more than 1 pages then sub-total1 should be equal to sub-total2 of previous page, and sub-total2 should be equal to sum of line amounts + sub-total1

Comment: It is easy to add subtotals for each group, and they will automatically use the scope of whatever subgroup they are for. I can't think of anything off the top of my head for page-related subtotals though, you have to use expressions that respect formatting AND groups, I've never really had a need to do that. A quick search turned up a few promising leads, (https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/sqlserver/en-US/ea075abe-8742-4b15-901d-e88cdbd4577e/show-sub-total-in-all-pages-in-ssrs, as well as others) though I don't have time right now to research more. Good luck!